# Equivalent orthogonal representations are orthogonaly equivalent

Tags: reference-request, rt.representation-theory

Could anyone point me to a reference for the following fact :

Let $G$ denote the orthogonal or symplectic complex group and $H$ be a complex Lie group, then if $\rho_1\,:H\, \rightarrow G$, $\rho_2\,:H\, \rightarrow G$ are two equivalent representations (conjugated by the linear group), they are conjugated by the group $G$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See Theorem 2.1 (b) in arXiv:math/0505268 [math.SG] for the symplectic case. The orthogonal case should be similar.